# Keyboard shortcut to wrap text in a command in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

If I want to make text bold in Overleaf I can select the text and hit Ctrl+B to turn it from `my text` into `\textbf{my text}`. If I want to do the same with another command such as `\section{}` I need to, annoyingly, type `\section{`, delete the additional `}` which automatically appears, tab to the end, then type `}` in the correct position.

I am wondering if there is functionality in Overleaf to automatically put selected text inside of any given command such as `\section{}`. For instance, any way of creating a custom keyboard shortcut which wraps selected text inside a specific command.

In Sublime text, for instance, I could achieve this functionality be recording a macro which adds any text around a selected text snippet, and then bind a key to that macro.

Comment: That is probably something you have to talk to overleaf support about as it is not related to latex and friends as such

Comment: Are questions about overleaf not on-topic here?

Comment: We are not a support forum for editor issues/requests in overleaf.

Comment: [Support questions about overleaf off-topic?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8045/support-questions-about-overleaf-off-topic)

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been closed due to lack of details or clarity, I am describing a clear issue and even provide a clear answer for the question. Can whoever closed the question provide an explanation so that I can improve the post?

Comment: I agree that this is on-topic and not "lacking clarity", so I voted to reopen. However, I do still think the question should be improved in order to be useful. It is rather long-winded for a rather simple question. Also, the title could be improved. "Shortcut for ..." is much more findable than "Quickly do ...". Just mentioning some possibilities for improvement that may sway others to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the support team of Overleaf, this functionality is not yet available (2023-06-08).

Comment: You do not need to include a date, every post on this side has that automatically attached to it. Also, you say "yet". Did Overleaf support mention that this is on the roadmap?

Comment: They "think it is a good idea and have passed it on to their product team for consideration in the future". I'll let others prophesise about the future of this functionality :)